# Know the last number equal to another within an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

```
const numbersArray = [5, 3, 1, 3, 4, 5, 3, 1];

var pastNumbers = [];

for (let i = 0; i < numbersArray.length; i++) {
  const number = numbersArray[i];
  pastNumbers.push(number);
  var count = 0;
  pastNumbers.forEach((v) => (v === number && count++));
  console.log(`There are ${count} numbers before equal to ${number}. The last equal number is in the ${???} position.`);
}
```

I have an array called `pastNumbers` that stores the numbers that were previously traversed by the `for` loop of another array called `numbersArray`. Then with `forEach` I get the amount of previous numbers equal to `number`.

I want to know the position of the last number equal to `number` within the `pastNumbers` array.
How can I do it?

Comment: Please add the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Updated with for loop*

Use an object instead of array to track, it makes it a bit easier.

In this example, I'm going over each number and adding the position at the beginning (`unshift`) to pastNumber[number].

I'm using unshift so that the first item is the last position registred. That way I can look up with `[0]` instead of using `[$.length-1]` (but I'm still still using the length anyway so you `push` is fine too ‍♂️)

```js
const numbersArray = [5, 3, 1, 3, 4, 5, 3, 1];
const pastNumbers = {};

for (let i = 0; i < numbersArray.length; i++) {
  const number = numbersArray[i];
  if (!pastNumbers[number]) {
    pastNumbers[number] = [];
  }
  if (pastNumbers[number].length > 0) {
    console.log(
      `There are ${pastNumbers[number].length} numbers before equal to ${number}. The last equal number is in the ${pastNumbers[number][0]} position.`
    );
  }
  pastNumbers[number].unshift(i);
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the `for` loop is necessary for the rest of my code.

Comment: you can replace `numbersArray.forEach` easily with a for loop